# Is there a command for secure move equivalent to scp and srm?

Tags: files, security, directory, move, delete

I'm looking for a command that allows me to securely move a file or directory.

If it doesn't exist, is my only option to write a shell script that

1. securely copies the item to the destination
2. compares source and destination
3. securely deletes the source

Comment: What do you mean by "securely" here?  What problem are you wanting to solve that regular `cp` or `mv` fails at?

Comment: I need to make sure that the original file is mainly securely deleted such as with `srm` after the move, but having a secure copy (using ssh for the data transfer) would improve the solution even more.

Answer (score 2):

I think `rsync` matches with your desired command. `rsync` is a fast and extraordinarily versatile file copying tool. For More Info  [Look Here](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/rsync.htm)

Comment: I had a look at `rsync`, but it doesn't seem to have an option for *securely* syncing files. Also, AFAIK `rsync` copies (syncs) files, but doesn't really move them as such.

Comment: @AlexIxeras `rsync` often runs inside `ssh`, so it is protected from viewing or modifications over the wire when that happens.  With the `--remove-source-files` option, it will delete the source side after the transfer is complete.

Comment: @BowlOfRed Ok, so I need to wrap the execution of `rsync` in ssh, but does the `remove-source-files` option also *securely* remove, ie. wipe/overwrite, the source file?

Comment: @AlexIxeras, you don't need to wrap it.  The standard method of running it will use ssh if you specify a remote source or remote destination.  It simply issues a normal delete.  (Not all filesystems will do anything useful if you try to overwrite a file the way `srm` attempts to do it)

Comment: @BowlOfRed My initial use case for a "secure move" was to move files locally, but ensuring that the original file gets securely deleted. — I should've clarified the "overwrite": I'm aware that `srm` works differently to a simple overwrite (and most of the time I need to use the `-mz` option). I just needed to word it.